# Using ListPicker and DataBinding

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, listpicker

Ok. I give up.
I want to use ListPicker control in one of my Windows Phone apps. I am getting an Exception **SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value**.

This is my XAML piece of ListPicker:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="CategoryPicker"                                     
           FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryPickerFullModeItemTemplate}" 
           Margin="12,0,0,0"                                    
           ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList}"                                        
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}"
           ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed"      
           FullModeHeader="Pick Categories" 
           CacheMode="BitmapCache" 
           Width="420" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

`CategoryList` is an `ObservableCollection<Category>` in my ViewModel.
`SelectedCategory` is a property in my ViewModel of type Category.

This is how I am declaring both CategoryList and SelectedCategory:

```
private Category _selectedCategory;// = new Category();


        private ObservableCollection<Category> _categoryList = new ObservableCollection<Category>();

        public ObservableCollection<Category> CategoryList
        {
            get
            {
                return _categoryList;
            }

            set
            {
                _categoryList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CategoryList");
            }
        }


        public Category SelectedCategory
        {
            get
            {
                 return _selectedCategory;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedCategory == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _selectedCategory = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCategory");
            }
        }
```

Appreciate your help!!! Maybe I have not understood the usage of ListPicker very well.

Comment: Hi there @RajeevNair, could you share your answer? I also have a problem just like you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058162/listbox-navigation-page-mvvm-light-in-windows-phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my answer to this question:
[Silverlight ComboBox binding with value converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637583/silverlight-combobox-binding-with-value-converter/9638478#9638478)

The short answer is that the selected item must be an item that is contained within the collection. Your getter is setting the selected item to a new object. This new object is not contained within the collection

Comment: that was a typo. I removed the line from the getter. Still the same error. I will look into your link you posted.

Comment: I use ListPickers in my own apps with the "same" code. I tried adding the same xaml as you have w/o the FullModeItemTemplate (as I don't know what it is). The only time you get the error is if your selected item is not an item that is contained within the collection. You are allowed to have the selected item be null, but it cannot be an item that is not in the collection

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. I was not assigning the SelectedCategory properly when loading the screen. And that was causing lot of headaches. Your response gave me a perspective and lead me the right way to find the bug! Thanks much. Now let me go and bang my head against the wall! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect the object returned by SelectedCategory to be one of the objects from the CategoryList collection.  In your example you are instanciating it within the get, so this is definitely not the case.

If CategoryList contains some values, then perhaps initialize _selectedCategory to null, and then in the get

```
if(_selectedCategory == null) {
   _selectedCategory = CategoryList.First();
}
```

Comment: Damian, thanks for your input. Your response also helped in initialzing the SelectedCategory property at the right place. Both Shawn's and yours response led to me the correct the problem. The irony is that I could not mark both your response as answer. Consider yourself marked too.