# Adding Listpicker on click

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to add Listpickers one by one on clicking a button meanwhile the controls down to the Listpickers should move downwords on each addtion of listpicker.Suggest me an idea plz.

XAML code for creating listpicker.

```
   <toolkit:ListPicker Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5,76,226,-52" x:Name="list" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" ItemCountThreshold="3"
                            FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}"   FullModeHeader="Select your Monthly Debts:" SelectedIndex="2"  CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                            FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="32" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"/>
```

C# code:

```
   List<payment> source = new List<payment>();
        source.Add(new payment() { Name = "Car Payment" });
        source.Add(new payment() { Name = "Credit UnionLoan" });
        source.Add(new payment() { Name = "Spousal Support" });
        source.Add(new payment() { Name = "Child Support" });
        source.Add(new payment() { Name = "Visa" });
        source.Add(new payment() { Name = "MasterCard" });
        this.list.ItemsSource = source;
```

Payment class file:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace NewUIChanges
{
public class payment
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You want code for adding ListPicker dynamically? or idea for moving the other elements downwards while adding?

Comment: Check the update above,the question is can i make instances of this listpicker on each click (max 8).and also idea of moving other elements downwards while adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ListPickers dynamically to the UI just like any other control.

And for your other requirement of moving other controls downwards, I would suggest you to make a small change to your ListPicker XAML code you showed above.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelListPickers" Grid.Row="0">
<toolkit:ListPicker  Margin="5,76,226,-52" x:Name="list" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" ItemCountThreshold="3"
                        FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}"   FullModeHeader="Select your Monthly Debts:" SelectedIndex="2"  CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                        FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="32" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and then in the code behind where you want to add the ListPickers do the following:

```
//Generate a dynamic listpicker
ListPicker lp = new ListPicker() { Name = "List2" };
lp.Template = this.Resources["PickerItemTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
lp.FullModeItemTemplate = this.Resources["FullModeItemTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
//And all other properties of "lp" as you need ..I am not writing all here

//Now add this new Listpicker to the stackpanel which is the child of the Grid
this.StackPanelListPickers.Children.Add(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your ListPicker and use the binding to an ObservableCollection.

The advantage of the ObsarvableCollection is that your change are automaticly updated on the view.
See : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for more informations.
Also have a look at [stackoverflow.com/questions/9745279](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745279/using-listpicker-and-databinding)